# How can I resend an invitation to Stack Careers 2.0

Tags: support, jobs

I sent an invitation to a friend, however they accidentally deleted the invitation and cannot retrieve it. So:

- How can I resend the invitation to them?
- Do I need to use a separate address?
- If so will the old invite be refunded?
- Are invitations refunded if they expire?

Comment: Check the trash folder?

Comment: Failed, one of those freak deletes that are synchronized across multiple devices ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize I am 2 days late getting to you, and right now I only see one invitation sent from your account and it was accepted.

To answer your questions:

- We do not have a way to resend, however they will be sent a reminder after 3
  days if they do not respond to the invitation.
- You can use a separate address, and that would work fine.
- No the old one would not be refunded.  The implicit assumption is that you
  are sending these invites to people who you know who want one, and the expectation
  is that they will accept.
- Invitations are not refunded if they expire, but that's something
  I'll bring up with the team.

If you still need help, please let me know what I can do for you.

Comment: Well thanks, seems like the invitation just took a long time to get there, thanks a lot for the clarifications too

Comment: One of the invitations I sent was never received. Does the "reminder after 3 days" still go out?